# Custom UIStoryboardSegue not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, uikit, uistoryboardsegue

I'm trying to write my own, custom `UIStoryboardSegue` in which a `UIView` 'slides' from the `sourceViewController` to the `destinationViewController`. Currently, I have the code below:

```
- (void)perform {
    UIViewController *sourceViewController = self.sourceViewController;
    UINavigationController *navigationController = [[self sourceViewController] navigationController];
    RestaurantViewController *destinationViewController = self.destinationViewController;

    destinationViewController.colors.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 10, 10);

    [sourceViewController.view addSubview:destinationViewController.tables];

    [UIView animateWithDuration:10.0
                          delay:0.0
                        options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut
                     animations:^{
                         destinationViewController.tables.frame = CGRectMake(100, 100, 100, 100);
                     }
                     completion:^(BOOL finished){
                         [destinationViewController.tables removeFromSuperview]; // remove from temp super view
                         [navigationController pushViewController:destinationViewController animated:NO]; // present VC
                     }];
}
```

As a test, I'm just playing around with the frame of the tables view. I also set the duration to a whopping 10 seconds, so that I could see everything. However, the `destinationViewController` is just snapping into place, completely ignoring all the code I wrote. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hello I am trying with your code to make this work, but I found that your main problem is that your `destinationViewController.tables` is nil that is why nothing seems to work.

You need to secure that your `destinationViewController.tables` is not nil, you can do this in your `RestaurantViewController` class with something like this

```
    - (instancetype)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)coder
      {
        self = [super initWithCoder:coder];
        if (self) {
            self.tables = [[UIView alloc]initWithCoder:coder];
         }
       return self;
      }
```

Hope this help you. Sorry for my english